# Codesigning on the mac with dynamic resources

Tags: centos, osx-mavericks, code-signing, osx-yosemite

We have a mac application that we build with jenkins and is signed on a Mac.
When the user download the dmg we add the database (with some last minute query) into the Application.app file. 
The dmg is located on a CentOS server so we can't recodesign when it is shipped.

We where able to do this thanks to an exclusion in the codesigning with `--resource-rules` 
Now with the latest update of Mavericks (10.9.5) and Yosemite we can't do this anymore because it is rendered obsolete. ([see link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG205))

So my question is: Does anyone has an idea on how to do the codesigning for Mavericks (10.9.5) and up with dynamic resources?